# rails add column to user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have user model and I want to add unique string key to all user records.Column name should be unsubscribe_key.

**Before migration** user record :

```
id = 1
username = "text"

id = 2
username = "abc"
```

**After migration** user record :

```
id = 1
username = "text"
unsubscribe_key = "5HQdTSsNRY6YCodmzr"

id = 2
username = "abc"
unsubscribe_key = "Jlewfw0324Lwp0sefr"
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 36):

Well, the easy part is adding the new column. On the shell:

```
rails generate migration AddUnsubscribeKeyToUsers unsubscribe_key:string
rake db:migrate
```

Also, you'll want to make this new attribute accessible in your user model:

### app/models/user.rb

```
attr_accessible :unsubscribe_key #along with all your other accessible attributes
```

Next, you'll need to add the unique keys. You could write some SQL code for that, or create a ruby script you can run within the rails console.

### lib/add_unique_keys.rb

```
module AddUniqueKeys
  KeyGenCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
  extend self
  def addUnsubscribeKeysToAllUsers
     users = User.all
     users.each do |u|
        u.update_attributes(:unsubscribe_key => generateKey(18))
     end
  end

  def generateKey(keyLength)
     key = ""
     keyLength.times do 
       key += generateKeyCharacter
     end
     key
  end

  def generateKeyCharacter
     KeyGenCharacters[rand(KeyGenCharacters.length)-1]
  end
end
```

Now go back to the shell and type `rails console`. On the ruby command line:

```
>>require "add_unique_keys.rb"
=> true
>>AddUniqueKeys.addUnsubscribeKeysToAllUsers
=> #Should print out array of users
```

If all goes well, your new column should be filled in with random strings.

Comment: Going back over Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, I realize this could be included in a Migration class. That way you could just run `rake db:migrate` from any terminal and get the same effect.

Comment: On third thought, this key generator is not very secure. You should use a real key generator like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
 $ rails g migration AddUnsubscribe_keyToUsers unsubscribe_key:string
```

Then

```
 $ rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the solution.

```
class AddUnsubscribeTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :unsubscribe_key, :string, :unique => true
        User.all.each do |user|
            user.unsubscribe_token = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(18)
        end
  end
  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :unsubscribe_key
  end
end
```

Comment: Answered your own question. Kudos! I thought you needed alphanumeric characters, though.

Comment: Also, you meant `user.unsubscribe_key = ...`

Comment: and you need to save the model, that will just set the token for the model, then toss it out for the garbage collector.

Comment: I like your migration solution better, but you need to make the appropriate edits so that it's 100% correct and then accept your answer so it will appear above mine when people search for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.0 add single column or multiple column using easy way..
https://gist.github.com/pyk/8569812